# Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: javascript, node.js

i write a node program,and i encounter a big difficult.

the server side code is below:

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var socketio=require("socket.io");
var server=require("http").Server(app);
var ws=socketio.listen(server);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(3000);
ws.on('connection',function(socket){
socket.on("message",function(msg){
    console.log("got:"+msg);
    socket.send('pong');
    });
});
```

the client side code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>websocket echo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>websocket echo</h1>
<h2>latency:<span id="latency"></span>ms</h2>
<script>

var lastMessage;
window.onload=function(){
    //create socket

    var ws=new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000");
    ws.onopen=function(){
        //send first ping
        ping();
    };
    // 监听Socket的关闭
    ws.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log('Client notified socket has closed',event);
    };
    ws.onmessage=function(ev){
        console.log("got:"+ev.data);

        document.getElementById("latency").innerHTML=new Date-lastMessage;
        ping();
    };
    function ping(){
        lastMessage= + new Date;
        ws.send("ping");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

there is the tip in chrome console:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response (index):16
Client notified socket has closed CloseEvent

Comment: Why not to use `socket.io` both for server and client? It takes care about connections.

Comment: this code is totally invalid, you are `not using websockets` at all. You are `using socket` on your server file, but you are trying to connect to websocket from your client side snippet. Refer here for [websocket usage example](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node#usage-examples)

Comment: @Ravi He's using socket.io, not ws. Socket.io upgrades the connection from polling to websockets if it's supported, therefore you need to use the socket.io library served on `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

Comment: @Ben thanks for the info.
@user3543469 you can include `socket.io.js` as mentioned by Ben, like this: `<script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: thank you.i have solved my problem changing socket.io to ws.

Comment: Probably not a solution to the original question, but I was trying to get socket.io to work with restify and CORS and at some point added this:  io.set("origins", "*");  Removing that solved a similar error message I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments this happens because socket.io should be connected with it's own client. You should either use websockets or socket.io on both sides.